# Create a blind footnote

Tags: footnotes

How can I create a `blind footnote` such as the one in the picture below?

[image]

By blind I mean that there is no number in the text, or in the footnote. I would like to have this footnote on the bottom of the first page of my document and all the other footnotes in the document should be unaltered.

Comment: What have you tried? Where in your document does this occur? Are other footnotes required to be numbered? If so, should the number of this one not appear or should this one not be numbered?

Comment: @cfr - updated question with answers to your comment.

Comment: @percusse: Different type of question with the same answer. I would suggest this is a duplicate. Perhaps add `\newcommand{\blindfootnote}[1]{{\renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnotetext{#1}}}` and use `\blindfootnote{<footnote>}` wherever you need a "blind footnote".

Comment: @Werner - That command solved my problem. I agree it is duplicate but I believe this title is more intuitive for the scope of the question.

Comment: @Matteo: I've upvoted this question as I agree with you in terms of the wording. To that end, it will remain here even when/if the question is closed as a duplicate. You could upvote the linked answers as "a form of acceptance."

Comment: @Matteo You can answer your own question too. I think leaving this as is, is more beneficial for searching purposes. But closing as duplicate will link them anyhow so who finds this will find that too.

Comment: @percusse - Thanks for finding that answer btw! Also, I think it's better to leave it like this and give them credit for the answer. On a side note, I just posted this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239421/adding-somebody-elses-answer-to-a-question

Comment: Meta.SO is not exactly the right  place to discuss these things as you are starting to experience :) Next time try our meta to limit the scope of fun :P